# I cannot set my Electron windows sizes using variables

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to read the height and width data from config.ini file for set them for `BrowserWindow`. But even though I check the variables if they are correct my Electron window sets it to 800x600. Here is my code:

```js
app.on("ready", () => {
    //Reading the config.ini file
    //config.ini file uses in main process, preferences.json uses in renderer process
    function readConfig(callback) {
        fs.readFile('./config.ini', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
            if (err) data = undefined;
            callback(data);
        });
    }

    //I use callback because I wanted to be sure file be readen before initilazing the window.
    readConfig(function(data) {
        if (data !== undefined && data !== null) {
            let config = ini.parse(data);
            windowH = config.height;
            windowW = config.width;
        }
        startApp(windowW, windowH);
    });
});
```

startApp() function:

```js
function startApp(w,h) {
    //Electron Window
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        frame: false,
        width: w,
        height: h,
        minWidth: 800,
        minHeight: 600,
        backgroundColor: '#1f2646',
        icon: __dirname + '/icon.ico',
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
            enableRemoteModule: true
        }
    });

    console.log(mainWindow.getSize()); //Prints [800, 600]
    console.log("Width:"+w.toString()); //1800
    console.log("Height:"+h.toString()); //1200
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out immediately, the data I read from config.ini is a string. I cannot believe  how I missed that part.